# Can summing a column in a PANDAS DataFrame really work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

The Python code below tries to total one column of a PANDAS DataFrame. I specify the column name in the df['Totals'].sum() context. When the print(total) command executes, it prints the Totals value for each of the twenty-nine columns. It will not total. I use loc and the same thing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
"""
Read csv file content into a PANDAS Dataframe.
"""
df = pd.read_csv("C:/amazon-orders.csv")
#df.head()
#df.shape


"""
If you want to avoid truncating (or squishing)
data display, use the following set_options.
"""
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

"""
Now display the data in the PANDAS Dataframe unedited.
"""
#Print Dataframe
print(df)

# Get total all values in column 'Totals' of the DataFrame
totals = df['Totals'].sum()
print(totals)
```

Comment: Can you update your code to be a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Something that can be copied into a clean workspace and reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: Do you have 29 columns identically labeled `'Totals'`, because that's the only way that should happen?

Comment: @ALollz It's kind of weird that you would even know that. :)